# How to replace whitespace character with percent in windows command line?

Tags: cmd

I want to find out how I can replace a whitespace character with a % in windows command line.

I currently have this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /P MY_TEXT=ENTER TEXT:
SET SPACE 2PROCENT=
set NEW_TEXT=%MY_TEXT: =test% 
MSG * %NEW_TEXT%
```

This gives as result: SETtestSPACEtest2PROCENT=

However, if I try to replace this with percent:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /P MY_TEXT=ENTER TEXT:
SET SPACE 2PROCENT=
set NEW_TEXT=%MY_TEXT: =%%% 
MSG * %NEW_TEXT%
```

I get as result: SET SPACE 2PROCENT=%%

So, I know I normally need to put two percents (%%) if I want to get % in the command line. However, in this case in my code I want to pass %% in between two other %. The problem that I have is that the code will start with a % and find the first % and then stop the code.

How can I put a % in between two others %'s to replace a whitespace character?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The above batches are identical. It isn't sufficient to `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` you also need to use `!` instead of the `%` to have it in effect. So use `set NEW_TEXT=!MY_TEXT: =%%! `

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid. You had to write (for the 2nd occasion, where you want to replace space with 2 percent signs (`%` -> `%%`)):

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /P "MY_TEXT=ENTER TEXT: "
SET "SPACE 2PROCENT="
set "NEW_TEXT=!MY_TEXT: =%%%%!"
rem The above only for the 2nd piece of code provided.
MSG * %NEW_TEXT%
```

If you want your 1st piece of code you provided to us working, then this is what you have to write:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /P "MY_TEXT=ENTER TEXT: "
SET "SPACE 2PROCENT="
set "NEW_TEXT=!MY_TEXT: =test%%!"
MSG * %NEW_TEXT%
```

Hope this helps!